# How to redirect multiple types of users to their respective Activities in realtime firebase database?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I have 3 types of users. I wanted redirect 3 kinds of users **(STUDENTS, TEACHERS, COORDINATOR)** to their respective activities after they login in android studio using `Realtime` `Firebase Database`

I have already tried using `Firebase` authentication and its successfully login for single user but I want it for three different user to their 3 activities.

```
package com.example.studentcoordinator;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.LoginFilter;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class Login_Form extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText txtEmail, txtPassword;
    Button btn_login;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    RadioGroup radioGroup;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login__form);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Login Page");

        txtEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signinemail);
        txtPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signinpassword);
        btn_login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginbutton);
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        radioGroup = findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);


        btn_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String email = txtEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                String password = txtPassword.getText().toString().trim();
                String USER_TYPE_1 = "student";
                String USER_TYPE_2 = "teacher";

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {

                    Toast.makeText(Login_Form.this, "Please Enter Valid Email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {

                    Toast.makeText(Login_Form.this, "Please Enter Valid Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                if (password.length() < 6) {
                    Toast.makeText(Login_Form.this, "Password Too Short", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                displayloader();


                firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(Login_Form.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                                    Intent intent = new Intent(Login_Form.this, Coordinator_homepage.class);
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                    startActivity(intent);

                                } else {
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Failed Or User Not Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }

                            }
                        });

            }
        });


    }

    public void displayloader() {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login_Form.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Logging .. Please Wait !!");
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you put conditions that check if the user is a teacher or a student in your onClick method. Like:

```
 if(userType.equals(UserType_1)){
      //Call intent for Student's Activity
  }
 if(userType.equals(UserType_2)){
     // Call intent for Teacher's Activity
  }
```

Make sure that you have created three different activities for the different users.

Although I would suggest you to create on main Activity and Three different Fragments. It will make your application lighter. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: Where to mention this if condition. Please explain me in details.

Comment: in the FirebaseAuthentication if(task.isSuccessful()){if(userType.equals(UserType_1)){// Student Activity intent } }